# Define a Map for Tree data in Haskell

Tags: haskell, dictionary, tree

I have the a `Tree` data structure like this:

```
data Tree a = ATree a [Tree a] 
            deriving Show
```

Is it possible to write a higher-order function `traverse` with the following declaration which just traverses (or whatever) the tree and reconstructs it?

```
traverse :: (a -> b) -> Tree a -> Tree b
```

Please note the `traverse`s signature. It doesn't get a list of Tree. It only accepts one node at a time.

I think the signature needs to change to accept lists in order to do this. Like this:

```
traverse :: (a -> b) -> [Tree a] -> [Tree b]
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
traverse :: (a -> b) -> Tree a -> Tree b
traverse f (ATree e l) = ATree (f e) (map (traverse f) l)
```

Note your function has the same signature as `fmap` so you should implement `Functor` for your type:

```
instance Functor Tree where
    fmap f (ATree e l) = ATree (f e) (fmap (traverse f) l)
```

in fact you can have the compiler generate your functor instance for you:

```
{-# LANGUAGE DeriveFunctor #-}

data Tree a = ATree a [Tree a] deriving (Show, Functor)
```

Comment: Thanks but I don't wanna use `map`. It's supposed to simulate map for this Tree.

Comment: @PetterBjao - So you want to write your own instance of `map` for lists as well?

Comment: I know how to write a map function but I was asked to write the above function which can act as a map for Tree. Map takes a function and a list and it gives another list. But here the given function declaration just receives one element and not a list. I'm a bit confused. That's why I asked.

Comment: Hey Lee, the above code works for me but can you explain why `(map (traverse f) l)` works? Traverse requires a function and a Tree. But here we only give a function. How does it work?

Comment: @PetterBjao `traverse f` is equivalent to the function `\t -> traverse f t`, thanks to partial application and eta-expansion.